# Delegate code generation UML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml

Hi i am using model generation tool from VS2012 with a UML project design.

Problem is VS refuses to generate code from a delegate class (its a class stereotype).
I tried a lot of things to make it work and there is not much documentation. Seems like nobody have this problem, maybe its something wrong about the class? here an example:

```
public class Class1
{
      public delegate void Test();
}

public class Class2
{
      public event Class1 TestEvent();
      public virtual void OnTestEvent()
      {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
      }
}
```

Also VS doesn't let me declare a function as delegate (i cant see the option) and i need to declare a class as an delegate so i can put events on other class. Its really driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to create a Delegate..?

Comment: following this tutorial http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to create a Delegate

```
Class MyClass
{
    private delegate void SomeFunctionDelegate(int param1, bool param2);
    private SomeFunctionDelegate sfd;

    public MyClass()
    {
        sfd = new SomeFunctionDelegate(this.SomeFunction);
    }

    private void SomeFunction(int param1, bool param2)
    {
        // Do stuff

        // Notify user
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        // Do stuff

        sfd.BeginInvoke(34, true, null, null);
    }
}
```

[Zurück

Delegates and Events in C# / .NET](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)

Comment: How about making it on VS2012 modeling project, the problem is not creating an delegate function, the problem is VS UML generation tool doesn't want to generate the code for the delegate class...